# Javafx Checkbox with Link as the label

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to create a Javafx Checkbox that has a Link as the label. When the link is clicked it will open the link, but when the checkbox is clicked it will check the box. Is this possible to do with the standard Javafx Checkbox?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I need to keep track of the url that goes with each `Checkbox`, and I will potentially have hundreds of `Checkboxes`.

Comment: `checkBox.setGraphic( new Hyperlink( "foo.bar" ) );`

Comment: That may actually work. Let me think about it some more.

Comment: @AndreyM I will give that a try.

Comment: @AndreyM You're answer is what I was looking for. If you create an answer I will mark it as best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox( "" );
checkBox.setGraphic( new Hyperlink( "foo.bar" ) );
```